# Issue with serializing byte array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, serialization, objectoutputstream

I'm trying to send files from server to client via ObjectOutputStream. I thought it is an easier way to use this stream both for sending different objects as well as raw file data.

I'm sending byte array size as `Integer`, raw data itself as `byte[]` and byte array hash code as `Integer` in a loop, and finishing both server and client after sending `-1` as size. So, each iteration there are three objects to send.

However, it's not working properly - the client gets the correct size and hash, but it also get same `byte[]` array again and again in each iteration.

Code of the client:

```
int size;
byte[] buf;
while ((size = (int) in.readObject()) > 0) {
    fOut.write((buf = (byte[]) in.readObject()), 0, size);
    System.out.printf("%d\tvs\t%d%n", Arrays.hashCode(buf), (int) in.readObject());
}
```

Code of the server:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[(int) MB];
int bufSize;
while ((bufSize = fileReader.read(buf)) != -1) {
    out.writeObject(bufSize);
    out.writeObject(buf);
    out.writeObject(Arrays.hashCode(buf));
}
out.writeObject(-1);
```

Both `out` and `in` in both client and server are:

```
in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
```

Client output:

```
Connecting...
Connection established
-1060163348 vs  -1060163348
-1060163348 vs  1768685466
-1060163348 vs  861707881
-1060163348 vs  1055789475
-1060163348 vs  -79313434
-1060163348 vs  385231183
-1060163348 vs  -633252012
...
```

As you can see - all byte[] are equals(

PS. Note that the first MB of the file was sent correctly. If the file is less than one MB in size it is also being sent properly.

Comment: And if I'm using classic function `.write()` of `ObjectOutputStream` I'm getting `java.io.OptionalDataException`. Even though I'm reading the correct number of bytes from the stream before reading any Object.

Comment: Note it may be easier to simply transfer the bytes from the file stream to the network stream instead of dealing with serialization.

Comment: Finally, after spending 4 hours on this issue - I agree)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess problem was that stream saves each written Object. So I read byte array from some kind of cache, not from socket...

However, it helps!

```
byte[] buf = new byte[(int) MB];
int bufSize;
while ((bufSize = fileReader.read(buf)) != -1) {
    out.writeObject(bufSize);
    out.writeObject(buf);
    out.writeObject(Arrays.hashCode(buf));
    out.reset(); // new line - it helps!!!!
}
out.writeObject(-1);
```